# Recommended Books for Cryptography : Theory and Implementation

Tags: implementation, protocol-design

It is a great idea if experts in Cryptography from mathematicians to security engineers introduce books and textbooks which they think is helpful or instructive for all people interested in the field.I didn't find such topic in previous posts.

I think a good format for answering would be like this:

I.
Theory, Analysis, Algorithms, Complexity,...
II.
Design, Implementation, Code Writing( in C/C++, Java,...),...
III.
History, Development, Future possibilities,...

Thanks in advance to all contributors for sharing your knowledge

Comment: Welcome to our site. We hope you find it useful. The reason you have not found similar questions to what you are looking for is that requests for books are considered [off topic on this particular site](http://meta.crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/1/do-we-want-literature-recommendations-and-similar-list-subjective-questions). A good place to discuss this would be in [Chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/784/cryptography) though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Theory and practice: Cryptography Engineering by Niels Ferguson, Bruce Schneier, and Tadayoshi Kohno

Design and some implementation tips are in Cryptography Engineering too. Code writing is highly dependant on the library you're using, so you should read its documentation first.

Development is covered, again, by Schneier's book. As for future possibilities: you'd need to subscribe to cryptography journals.

The older books (Practical Cryptography and Applied Cryptography) are good too, but don't cover the newest algorithms (AES, SHA-2, elliptic cryptography).

Comment: Katz/Lindell is a great intro to the theory side of things. The title is "Introduction to Modern Cryptography".